# Display Featured Records First Using JOIN/UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all

I have the following data from a table:

```
ID  Name        IsFeatured
1   Alpha       Yes
2   Echo        No
3   Delta       Yes
4   Charlie     Yes
5   Bravo       No
```

and I would like to display the featured records first, sorted in ascending order (name):

```
ID  Name        IsFeatured
1   Alpha       Yes
4   Charlie     Yes
3   Delta       Yes
5   Bravo       No
2   Echo        No
```

I use the following query to combine two separated queries but it won't allow me to use ORDER BY twice.

```
SELECT ID, Name, IsFeatured FROM table1 WHERE IsFeatured='Yes' ORDER BY Name
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, IsFeatured FROM table1 WHERE IsFeatured='No' ORDER BY Name
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to use Union. Just sort by Yes then No and by Name.
Provided that you only have Yes or No as values then sort by descending should do the trick.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  [Name],
  IsFeatured
FROM table1
ORDER BY IsFeatured desc,[Name]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as

```
SELECT ID, Name, IsFeatured 
FROM table1
ORDER BY IsFeatured DESC, Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` to get rows in a particular order:

```
SELECT ID, Name, IsFeatured
FROM table1 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN IsFeatured = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         Name;
```

SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  This is true except for a result set created by a query that has `ORDER BY` in the outermost `SELECT`.